# System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll

Tags: sql-server-ce, entity-framework-4.1

using nuget : add ef4.1 and sqlce4 but i got this when project uploded on my hosting space

Exception Details: System.Data.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
NModel.ssdl(2,86) : error 0004: Could not load System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll. Reinstall SQL Server Compact.

Answer (score 2):

Everything work fine if you add references with NuGet.

The required packages are:

- EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact
  (https://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact/4.3.4)
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact
  (https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact)

Comment: EntityFramework.SqlServer.Compact package cannot be install in .Net 3.5 projects, that's right?

Answer (score 0):

This same thing is happening to me. It happening over time somehow. When I first deploy to production server it works ok. But then the SDF file becomes corrupt or something and stops working. As a temp fix I just replace the sdf file. I will post more when I figure out the real issue.